# How to add branch policies using powershell Invoke RestMethod

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-repos

We have PowerShell script that will automate creating branch.

Now we are trying to automate branch policies using api using PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod.

We have option to manually add policies using cross repository policies, but we have build validation enabled for repositories which is different for each repo.

I'm able to get the policy configurations using `GET https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/policy/configurations/repo=$repoName&api-version=6.0`
But don't know how to get the get the particular value and add policies.

Comment: Raw Git does not have "branch policies" at all. Add-ons, as used on GitHub, Bitbucket, Azure, etc., add them—each in their own way, so it's good that you said "Azure" here. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Configurations - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/configurations/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) Rest API:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/policy/configurations/{configurationId}?api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

In the body you specify the branch policy you want to add, for example - build policy:

```
{
  "isEnabled": true,
  "isBlocking": false,
  "type": {
    "id": "0609b952-1397-4640-95ec-e00a01b2c241"
  },
  "settings": {
    "buildDefinitionId": 5,
    "scope": [
      {
        "repositoryId": null,
        "refName": "refs/heads/feature",
        "matchKind": "prefix"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In the above body you add branch (build) policy to branch `feature` that requires build `5` to pass.

You cans see all the available policy types in the [Types - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/types/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) api.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your quick response. I can able to add build validation now. Can we give name instead of ID? I mean, in json file, can i give Name and buildDefinition name instead of id and buildDefinitionId? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure :/ just try it :)

Answer (score 1):

To add the Build validation  in Branch Policy, you could refer to the following PowerShell Sample:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/policy/configurations?api-version=6.1-preview.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$JSON = @'
{
 "type":{
        "id":"0609b952-1397-4640-95ec-e00a01b2c241"
    },
    "revision":1,
    "isDeleted":false,
    "isBlocking":true,
    "isEnabled":true,
    "settings":{
        "buildDefinitionId":592,
        "displayName":null,
        "manualQueueOnly":false,
        "queueOnSourceUpdateOnly":true,
        "validDuration":720,
        "scope":[
            {
                "repositoryId":"RepoID",
                "refName":"refs/heads/BranchName",
                "matchKind":"Exact"
                }
                ]
            }
}
'@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method POST -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
```

You could refer to this doc about [Configurations - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/configurations/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#build-policy) and [Repositories - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your quick response.

I can able to add build validation now. Can we give name instead of ID? I mean, in above json file, can i give Name and buildDefinition name instead of id and buildDefinitionId?

Thanks!

Comment: @Kart. I am afraird that it can only support the ID and builddefinitionid. To clarify the id in type parameter, the id is point to Build Validation, you don't need to change the type id if you only want to add build validation.

Comment: I think we can only give id instead of name. Im able to add the build validation now. Could you please help me in cloning the build pipeline? I have collected the parameters and trying to POST this `$build_url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=5.0-preview.7"` but getting the below error.

Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: definition.Process","typeName":"System.ArgumentNullException, 
mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentNullException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}

Comment: You can check the answer in the ticket